# Convert Excel worksheets to individual csv files along with format in source

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have Excel files in one folder in xlxs format.

The code should check each file for sheets starting with name 'help' and convert these sheets to a csv format file.

I am not able to get the format in the source work sheet to the csv converted file of that worksheet.

Please include the code line in the below code posted

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Excel_CSV_Converter
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");



            if (officeType == null)

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Excel is not installed");

            }

            else

            {

                // Let us continue our work on Excel file conversion. 

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();



                // While saving, it asks for the user confirmation, whether we want to save or not.

                // By setting DisplayAlerts to false, we just skip this alert.

                app.DisplayAlerts = false;

                FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Select the Source Directory from Dialog box where excel files present "); // Prompt
                string SourceDir = string.Empty;
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    SourceDir = fbd.SelectedPath;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Selected source directory is " + SourceDir + "\n");

                Console.WriteLine(@"Select the Destination Directory where .csv files need to be saved"); // Prompt

                string DestinationDir = string.Empty;
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    DestinationDir = fbd.SelectedPath;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Selected Destination directory is " + SourceDir + "\n");
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourceDir + @"\", "*.XLSX");
                // Now we open the upload file in Excel Workbook. 

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    // This is to discard temporary excel files created in background.
                    if (file.Contains('$'))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(file);
                    string WorkbookName = excelWorkbook.Name;
                    foreach (Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet1 in excelWorkbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        if (xlWorksheet1.Name.StartsWith("help"))
                        {
                            string newFileName = DestinationDir + @"\" + WorkbookName.Split('.')[0] + " - " + xlWorksheet1.Name.Split('-')[0] + ".csv";
                            Console.WriteLine("Created " + newFileName + "\n");
                            // Now save this file as CSV file.
                            xlWorksheet1.SaveAs(newFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
                        }

                    }
                    // Close the Workbook and Quit the Excel Application at the end. 

                    excelWorkbook.Close();
                }
                app.Quit();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it creating any files with a CSV extension? If so, do they look malformed if you view them as text?

Comment: Yes. For Eg. In source Dir I have a file "qwerty" with sheets Summary, Help 1 and help 2/ The csv files are created for help1 and help 2 in the target. I am able to view the contents of the csv files. I wanted to know how do I format it in the same way as there in the sheet  "Qwerty" file

Comment: What do you mean by formatting? CSV are text files thus, they don't support formatting (ie bold, italic, colors...).

Comment: For Eg. Sap id is 000987 is text field in xls file. When converted to csv it will be not read it correctly.